# Disposing in Ninject

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dependency-injection, ninject

I use Ninject for DI, it creates DbContext per request (single for all services) and i usually call few service methods per request (so i can't dispose DbContext after first service method has been called).

The question is, should i make WallService or WallManager (and other services and managers) IDisposable and what Dispose logic create?

My Business Logic Layer

```
namespace MySite.BLL.Services
{
    public class WallService
    {
        WallManager wallManager;

        public WallService(MybContext db)
        {
            wallManager = new WallManager(db);
        }
     }
}
```

My Data Access Layer

```
namespace MySite.DAL.Repositories
{
    public class WallManager
    {
        MyDbContext db;
        public WallManager(MyDbContext db)
        {
            this.db = db;
        }
    }
}
```

NinjectWebCommon.cs

```
kernel.Bind<MyDbContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope().WithConstructorArgument<string>("MyMsSqlString");
kernel.Bind<WallService>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
```

MyBaseController.cs

```
public class MyBaseController : Controller
{
     [Inject]
     public WallService WallService { get; set; }

     // Other Services ..
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(This is more an extended comment than an answer)

I'm pretty certain you don't need to do this - and not only that you don't *need* to but you really *shouldn't* in this case.

The thing is, you are not creating the `DbContext` instance yourself - you're delegating that responsibility to the IOC library;in that respect the reference is only "passing through" so none of your classes own it and should not do anything that could trash it.

Also, `DbContext` is a managed object so you don't need to `Dispose` it anyway.
[There is a very good answer on this site about this notion already](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31843482/1362136), although it doesn't directly address your question hence I didn't mark as duplicate

One thing I've noticed about your code though.
You're injecting the `DbContext`, and then using it to create a `WallManager` instance. That's kind of defeating the purpose of Dependency Injection. Why not directly inject the `WallManager` into `WallService`?

i.e.

```
public class WallService
    {
        readonly WallManager _wallManager;

        public WallService(WallManager manager)
        {
            if (manager==null){
                 throw new ArgumentNullException("manager");
           }
            _wallManager = manager;
        }
     }
```

`Ninject` (or any other IOC Library) will have no problem figuring out that it needs to create and inject a `DbContext` into the `manager` dependency, once you have registered the `WallManager` type with it; the idea here is that you register all possible dependency types, and then the library builds the object graph for you.

This way you don't have to take a dependency on `DbContext` directly in your `WallService`...I am guessing you only take it in order to create the `WallManager` anyway - if you are *also* using `DbContext` in the `WallService` I would suggest you take another look at the design since you should limit your data access to one layer.

Comment: Thank you. I don't use DB directly at my BLL. I will inject managers into services